# Node.js: Socket.io doesn't work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've wrote a simple node.js app by socket.io some weeks ago. My program is fine on my PC but when i tried to run it on my laptop. I faced a really weird error on my console.
note that I'm running node on `127.0.0.1:2324`. I don't know what is that ip (`0.0.9.20`) on the chrome console.

Again, **my code is correct cause it's working fine on my PC**.
[image]
And I get this on my cmd:
[image]

my **paint.html** code is something like this:

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/node/paint/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/node/paint/js/cursor.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/node/paint/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/node/paint/js/core.js"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1:2324/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<link  href="http://127.0.0.1/node/paint/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**core.js**:

```
// broadcat function
    function broadcast(data)
    {
        var socketio = io.connect(serverPort);
        socketio.emit("message_to_server", { pen : data});
    }

    // receive data from server
    var socketio = io.connect(serverPort);
    socketio.on("message_to_client", function(data) 
    {
        var res_brush = data['pen'];
        var brush_data_rec = res_brush['pen'].split('|');
        draw(brush_data_rec[0],
             brush_data_rec[1],
             brush_data_rec[2],
             brush_data_rec[3],
             brush_data_rec[4],
             brush_data_rec[5],
             brush_data_rec[6]);
    });
```

update:
[image]

Comment: @hexacyanide I've updated the question. It's 2.33 am in here. and I have to represent it on 9 am. I'm a bit in hurry :(

Comment: If someone vote up my question. I would have enough reputation to set a bounty on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly specify the target hostname on the client to connect to to avoid confusing the client on which address to connect to. There's also a cleaner way to specify a target port.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/', {
  'port': 8080,
  'transports': ['websockets']
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it disappeared the console error but the functionality problem is still there. I get new error on cmd see the update.

Comment: It's falling back to XHR polling because websockets aren't working. Try restricting the transport options. I'll edit my post with it.

Comment: It's working you are a genius. Thanks. can you explain more about this property `'transports': ['websockets']` ?

Comment: Socket.IO is a multi-transport library, so if websockets fail, then it falls back to other things such as JSONP polling or XHR long-polling. By setting the only allowed transport to websockets, we prevent any fallback to other transports which were not working for you.

Comment: So the problem is still there. we just bypassed the problem to have the functionality. Am I right?

Comment: The debug you were seeing in console actually wasn't errors, it was just debug. I was referring to anything else that might have also been failing to work.